# Values Not Interested In From Hook Causes Re-Render

Tags: javascript, performance, react.js

This is the code ([here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-glitter-pn30l)):

```
import React, {
  useContext,
  useReducer,
  createContext
} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const stateReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return {
        count: state.count + 1
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const StateContext = createContext();

const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(stateReducer, {
    count: 0
  });

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useCount = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(StateContext);

  const changeCount = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "increment" });
  };

  return {
    ...state,
    changeCount
  };
};

const Caller = () => {
  const { changeCount } = useCount();

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    changeCount();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
        Test me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Main = () => {
  const { changeCount } = useCount();

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    changeCount();
  };

  console.log("main render");

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
        Click Me Boi!
      </button>
      <Caller />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <StateProvider>
    <Main />
  </StateProvider>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The issue is this:

My **Main** component uses a hook. that hook returns some state and a function (functions) to modify that state.

My main component, although uses the hook, only wants/cares about the modifying function of that hook, and as such deconstructs only the function.

When I call the hook's function, it causes a rerender of my main component.

I understand that, for example, if I have `useState` and call its function, that function will change, but if it's a `useReducer` and I am calling a displatch does it change?

Really my question comes down to this. Is there a way to stop my main component rendering here (because I only rely on the hook's functions and not the state) or would I have to change my implementation to allow the re-render of main and just use memo to save re-renders of the child components?